# First non empty cell in row Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I'm trying to find first non empty cell in a row using VBA .Find function. The code is as follow:

```
    Sub test()

    With Selection
    Set firstNE = .Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    End With
    Debug.Print firstNE.Address

    End Sub
```

The issue I'm having with it is when I select range e.g. B4:F4 and all cells in that range are non empty it returns C4 instead of B4.

The same happens when B4 is non empty, and then next non empty is e.g. E4, it returns E4 instead of B4.

It only returns B4 if all selection apart from B4 is empty.

Can someone explain it to me?

Btw. I don't want to use IsEmpty+loop as it is taking too much time to work through my data.

Comment: Try supplying the `After` argument as `Selection.cells(selection.cells.count)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try supplying the `After` argument:

```
Sub test()

    With Selection
       Set firstNE = .Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           After:=.Cells(.Cells.count))
    End With

    If Not firstNE Is Nothing Then Debug.Print firstNE.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. It solved my problem, and I've learnt something.